# awk: if pattern is matched append some data

Tags: awk, matching

I have a data set created by a tool with file name test.deg. The file contents is as follows:

```
1         I0.XPDIN1      1.581e-01  1.507e-01  3.662e-04  3.891e-02   
2         I0.XPXA1    1.577e-01  1.502e-01  3.653e-04  3.859e-02   
3         I0.XPXA2    1.538e-01  1.444e-01  3.552e-04  3.471e-02
```

I have a second file ,test.spf, containing the following information:

```
XPDIN1 XPDIN1#d XPDIN1#g XPDIN1#s VPP
XPXA1 XPXA1#d XPXA1#g XPXA1#s VPP
XPXA2 XPXA2#d XPXA2#g XPXA2#s VPP
```

I am trying to write an awk script that matches the Instance name from test.deg to the instance name in test.spf.  When the script sees a match I would like the 5th column's contents appended to that matched instance name's line end.  Example output for I0.XPDIN1 in test.deg would be XPDIN1 XPDIN1#d XPDIN1#g XPDIN1#s VPP 3.662e-04

The script needs to match the instance name from test.deg after the prefix I0. to the first instance name call in test.spf then add the 5th columns data.

Thanks,
Bad Awk

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Awk program to create age degraded sigma netlist 

chmod +x awk_for_age #creates runnable awk file 
./awk_for_age

awk -f program-file input-file1 input-file2

$ awk -v sq="'" 'BEGIN { print "Here is a single quote <" sq ">" }'
-| Here is a single quote <'>

awk '/I0./ { print $0 }' top.tmideg0 #prints the entire line containing I0. 

awk '/I0./ { print $2, $5 }' top.tmideg0 #prints the second and fifth argument for lines containing I0.

awk '/I0./ { print $2, $5 }' top.tmideg0 > top.tmideg01 same as prior but prints to newfile called top.tmideg01

Comment: This is my first time using awk and I felt the process of me learning basic usage may undermine the real problem I am trying to solve.  That being said, above, I posted the notes I have taken as well as lines of code to print from the my input file.  I hope this is helpful! I am knew to this world.  Thank you for the support xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Awk

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$5; next} ("I0."$1 in a){$6=a["I0."$1]}1' test.deg test.spf
XPDIN1 XPDIN1#d XPDIN1#g XPDIN1#s VPP 3.662e-04
XPXA1 XPXA1#d XPXA1#g XPXA1#s VPP 3.653e-04
XPXA2 XPXA2#d XPXA2#g XPXA2#s VPP 3.552e-04
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you.  I am going to make some changes because I have a very large netlist and want to create the number as a variable and add it (out of sight) to sigma variable.  That being said, this perfectly answered my question.  Thanks again